How to find the tenant where a multi-tenant AAD application was registered
I am trying to find in which of our test tenants an AAD application was registered. I know the application registration exists as I can successfully instantiate a new service principal for it in a different tenant:
New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId <app-id-for-MyTestApplication>
# I see that a service principal for app MyTestApplication is created

Is there a way for me to find the home tenant given the app ID?

Does this link help?

No @DimiTakis. Get-AzTenant is for "Get[ting] tenants that are authorized for the current user."

Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId "xxxxxxxx" | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

Get the return result:
{
    "AccountEnabled":  true,
    "AddIn":  [

              ],
    "AlternativeName":  [

                        ],
    "AppDescription":  null,
    "AppDisplayName":  "wbxxxxxx",
    "AppId":  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "AppOwnerOrganizationId":  "1111111-3a06-4480-8a1e-11111111",
    "AppRole":  [

                ],
    "AppRoleAssignedTo":  null,
    "AppRoleAssignment":  null,
    "AppRoleAssignmentRequired":  false,
    "ApplicationTemplateId":  null,
    "ClaimsMappingPolicy":  null,
    "CreatedObject":  null,
    "DelegatedPermissionClassification":  null,
    
    ...
}

AppOwnerOrganizationId is the service principal related app home tenant.

Thanks @wenbo. This works with the caveat that you need to first do the step in my question and create a service principal for the multi-tenant app. Then authenticate with the tenant where you created the service principal before running the command.
